# Facebook login: how to get email and profile picture in custom size?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I've a FB.login method that should get the email of the users from facebook but it always give me

> undefined

I've got the code from facebook developers page and **also with their test user that facebook provide I can't get the email**.

Another thing that I can't do is to get the profile picture in different size, the urls that I've found searching where there are height and width params won't work with my code.

> API version is v3.2

Here is the code that after connection get the information from profile

```
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/it_IT/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2&appId=405257833547582&autoLogAppEvents=1';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', {fields: 'last_name,first_name,email'}, function(response) {
    console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
    $.post("Oauth.php", //Required URL of the page on server
        { // Data Sending With Request To Server
            name:response.first_name,
            surname:response.last_name,
            user_id:response.id,
            type_connection:'facebook',
            email:response.email
        },
    function(response,status){ // Required Callback Function
        alert("*----Received Data----*nnResponse : " + response+"nnStatus : " + status);//"response" receives - whatever written in echo of above PHP script.
        $("#form")[0].reset();
    });
});
}
```

Comment: do you authorize your user? i do not see any login code. you cannot use the api without login.

Comment: yes of course i do, in fact I can get first and last name and profile pic in 50x50 size

Comment: make sure you get asked for the email permission in the login process. also, make sure you actually have an email attaced to your fb account.

Comment: No one is stopping me from sending any data I like to your `Oauth.php` script … The API request should be made on the server side to begin with! Send only the access token you get from the client-side login to the server.